# Codeigniter Getting data from two different models and show in one view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working o a project where I have clients and reservation. I can create new clients, fetch them and list them. However, on the reservation, I need to be able to show the client name that comes from one model and controller to my actual view, that is on reservation model and controller.

I'm listing clients, and adding a link to another page where I show the client name, the reservation ID and all the other information from the reservation.

I'm new at programming, I would really apreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

My client controller tha list the clients so I can make the reservation.

```
public function listarr(){
    $nome = $this->session->userdata("nome");
    $this->load->view("template/topo");
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->model('Clientes');
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'cliente/listarr';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Clientes->count_tblclientes();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    //$config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "</ul>";
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<li class ='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "</li>";



    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['tblclientes'] = $this->Clientes->fetch_tblclientes($config['per_page'], $page );
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['message'] = '';

    $this->load->view("cliente/listarr",$data, array (
        'nome' => $nome));
    $this->load->view("template/rodape");
}
```

My reservation controller where I want to show the name data coming from client and show the other data from reservation.

```
public function ficha_completa($id) {
    $this->load->view("template/topo");
    $this->load->model("Reservas", "rowDao");
     $resp = "";

    if($_POST){

    $nomecliente = $this->input->post("nomecliente");
        $datar = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $this->input->post("datar"))));
        $codcliente = $this->input->post("codcliente");
        $adultos = $this->input->post("adultos");
        $precoadulto = $this->input->post("precoadulto");
        $criancas = $this->input->post("criancas");
        $precocrianca = $this->input->post("precocrianca");
        $datasinal = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $this->input->post("datasinal"))));
        $valor = $this->input->post("valor");
        $obs = $this->input->post("obs");
        $data2 = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $this->input->post("data2"))));
        $valor2 = $this->input->post("valor2");
        $obs2 = $this->input->post("obs2");
        $data3 = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $this->input->post("data3"))));
        $valor3 = $this->input->post("valor3");
        $obs3 = $this->input->post("obs3");
        $locou = $this->input->post("locou");
        $excursao = $this->input->post("excursao");
        $referencia = $this->input->post("referencia");
        $grupo = $this->input->post("grupo");
        $obsfinal = $this->input->post("obsfinal");


        $data = array(
            'nomecliente' => $nomecliente,
            'datar' => $datar,
            'codcliente' => $codcliente,
            'adultos' => $adultos,
            'precoadulto' => $precoadulto,
            'criancas' => $criancas,
            'precocrianca' => $precocrianca,
            'datasinal' => $datasinal,
            'valor' => $valor,
            'obs' => $obs,
            'data2' => $data2,
            'valor2' => $valor2,
            'obs2' => $obs2,
            'data3' => $data3,
            'valor3' => $valor3,
            'obs3' => $obs3,
            'locou' => $locou,
    'excursao' => $excursao,
    'referencia' => $referencia,
    'grupo' => $grupo,
    'obsfinal' => $obsfinal,

        );

        $this->rowDao->atualizar($data);
        $resp = "Pessoa editada com sucesso!";
    }

    $row = $this->rowDao->buscarPorId($id);

    $this->load->view("reserva/ficha_completa", array(
        'row' => $row,
        'resp' => $resp
    ));
    $this->load->view("template/rodape");
}
```

My reservation model

```
 public function buscarPorId($id){
    $this->db->where("codreserva", $id);
    return $this->db->get("reservas")->first_row();
}
```

my html in view where the data will show

```
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Codigo do Cliente 
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="codcliente" name="nomecliente" value="<?php echo $row->nomecliente; ?>" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Codigo da Reserva 
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="codcliente" name="codreserva" value="<?php echo $row->codreserva; ?>" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name" >Data da reserva 
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="datar" name="datar" value="<?php echo $row->datar; ?>" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-inputmask="'mask': '99/99/9999'">
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Just to show also, this is the controller where I save the client data

```
    public function index(){
    $this->load->view("template/topo");
    $resp = "";
    //Se os dados chegarem via POST
    if($_POST){

        $NomeCliente = $this->input->post("NomeCliente");
        $Endereco = $this->input->post("Endereco");
        $Bairro = $this->input->post("Bairro");
        $Cidade = $this->input->post("Cidade");
        $UF = $this->input->post("UF");
        $CEP = $this->input->post("CEP");
        $CGC_CPF = $this->input->post("CGC_CPF");
        $DataNasc = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $this->input->post("DataNasc"))));
        $CodSexo = $this->input->post("CodSexo");
        $TelResid = $this->input->post("TelResid");
        $TelComerc = $this->input->post("TelComerc");
        $Ramal = $this->input->post("Ramal");
        $Celular = $this->input->post("Celular");
        $E_mail = $this->input->post("E_mail");
        $Telrecado = $this->input->post("Telrecado");
        $Fax = $this->input->post("Fax");
        $Observacoes = $this->input->post("Observacoes");




        $dados = array(
            'NomeCliente' => $NomeCliente,
            'Endereco' => $Endereco,
            'Bairro' => $Bairro,
            'Cidade' => $Cidade,
            'UF' => $UF,
            'CEP' => $CEP,
            'CGC_CPF' => $CGC_CPF,
            'DataNasc' => $DataNasc,
            'CodSexo' => $CodSexo,
            'TelResid' => $TelResid,
            'TelComerc' => $TelComerc,
            'Ramal' => $Ramal,
            'Celular' => $Celular,
            'E_mail' => $E_mail,
            'Telrecado' => $Telrecado,
            'Fax' => $Fax,
            'Observacoes' => $Observacoes,

        );

        //Carregar o Model Pessoas
        $this->load->model("Clientes", "pDao");
        if($this->pDao->gravar($dados))
            $resp = $NomeCliente . ", enviado com sucesso!";
        else
            $resp = $NomeCliente . ", nao enviado!";

    }

    $this->load->view("cliente/index", 
            array('resp' => $resp));
    $this->load->view("template/rodape");
}
```

Comment: What's your problem (I'm not getting it)? You could add various models in the same controller, just load it (`$this->load->model('Clientes'); $this->load->model('Other'); $this->other->function()`) and call to the desired function and attach the data in your array of data `$data`. The view will receive all the data you attach on it.

Comment: you can add multiple model in same controller. just load it.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you can load many model and put model data in singl view

in your controller load firstly your all modal

```
$this->load->model(array('modal1','modal2','modal3'));
```

**Controller**

```
 data['modaldata_1']=$this->modal1->model_1();
 data['modaldata_2']=$this->modal2->model_2();
 data['modaldata_3']=$this->modal3->model_3();
 //putting all data in view 
 $this->load->view('yourview',$data);
```

**View**
 you can print your data like.

```
 print_r($modaldata_1);
 print_r($modaldata_2);
 print_r($modaldata_3);
```